# Need help using sessions on php 5 apache 2.4 on windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, session

I have apache 2.4 and php 5 on a windows 7 machine, everything is working great. However, I can't make a session script work: it gives me a warning that file does not exist. I tried to set `session.save_Path="C:/tmp"` in php.ini as default, and still get the same warning. Looked online but didn't find anything. Only thing I didn't try was a path to the `htdocs` folder. However being a session file I guess that's not a good idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check if my edit haven't introduced any misinterpretations. Please remember to format your code properly.